# Programmatic extraction of Unicode character values from True type font file in C/C++

Tags: pdf, utf-8, truetype

I am trying to extract the UTF-8 character value from an embedded true type font file contained in a PDF. Is anyone aware of a method of doing this? The values in the PDF might be something like '2%dd! w!|<~' and this would end up as 'Hello World' in the PDF represented by the corresponding glyphs from the TTF. I'd like to be able to extract the wchar values here. Is this possible? Does the UTF-8 value for each character exist in the TTF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glyph ID's do not always correspond to Unicode character values - especially with non latin scripts that use a lot of ligatures and variant glyph forms where there is not a one-to-one correspondance between glyphs and characters.

Only Tagged PDF files store the Unicode text - otherwise you may have to reconstruct the characters from the glyph names in the fonts. This is possible if the fonts used have glyphs named according to Adobe's Glyph Naming Convention or [Adobe Glyph List Specification](http://sourceforge.net/adobe/aglfn/wiki/AGL%20Specification/) - but many fonts, including the standard Windows fonts, don't follow this naming convention.

Comment: So in the case that they do not follow standard glyph naming conventions, the unicode value for each characterId cannot be obtained without OCR?

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 is an encoding that allows UTF8 encoded streams to be decoded to reveal a sequence of unicode char points. In any case, PDF does not encode using UTF-8. For true type text, each glyph is encoded using 8 bits.

To decode:

1. Read the differences array and encoding from the font definition
2. Read 8 bits at a time and produce an "AdobeGlyphId" using the encoding and differences array read in step 1.
3. Use the adobe glyph id to look up the unicode value

This is detailed in section 9.10 of the PDF Specification